# How to use the R function: raster::extract with polygon which partly covers raster?

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, extract

I have a raster file which is only partly covered by a shapefile with polygons.

Now I want to apply raster::extract in order to get the mean value for each polygon based on the rasterfile - But some features of the shapefile are complete outside of the rasterfile.

If I'm using snow clusters in order to speed the extraction up - I get the following error:
R raster::extract Error in .local(x, y, ...) : cluster error at polygon: 1

Do you have an idea, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you make a simple reproducible example or even just some sample code? I can never remember how to run over snow clusters...

Comment: Should be handled out of the box with the `exactextractr` package, if you want to give it a try (I'm the author.) Should remove the need to use snow.

Comment: @dbaston thank you for your package! This works much fast compared to classical raster package and you can also use it with snow clusters! - Thanks!